# I can not update patch SUPEE-7405 v1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

With the help of this documentation http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

i tried to patch on my magento site. but it gives me error as follows

```
  [~/public_html/my_proj]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.3_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-46-32.sh
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php.rej

    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej

    patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
    Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php.rej
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the Magento version in your question.

Also, check the contents of `app/etc/applied.patches.list`. If you have previously installed other patches, they will be listed there.
And please read through the [release notes for SUPEE-7405 v.1.1](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.4.html) as it clearly states that you will need to install SUPEE-7405 v.1.0 before installing the version 1.1.

### Update

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej
```

What the log means is that while patching the file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php`, it has found that the file has already been patched. `Assume -R? [n]` is asking you if you want to reverse the patch, which by default is set to `[n]`.  Again, it is asking if the patch should be applied anyway (`Apply anyway? [n]`). And again it is set to No.

This means that the patch has already been applied to your site. To make sure of this, please check the `app/etc/applied.patched.list` file. Also, check the patch details if your version is affected by the patch or not. If you have the latest version, most probably, you will not need to apply the patch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My magento ver is 1.9.2.4 but i am not to look this file app/etc/applied.patches.list

Comment: Great, then you don't need to apply the patch as 1.9.2.4 already includes the patch 7405 v1.1. I will update my answer so that it may be useful to others as well.

Comment: +1 - Unlike most previous multi-release patches where you had to run the previous v1.0 patch to remove it before installing v1.1, this patch must explicitly have SUPEE-7405 v1.0 installed successfully, and then SUPEE-7405 v1.1 installed to modify the original v1.0 patch installation.